# Finding conservation quantities in Ising Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conservation-laws, quantum-spin, ising-model

I have a Ising model, for example:

> $$H =\sum_{<ij>}
>  J(\sigma_i^x\sigma_j^x+\sigma_i^y\sigma_j^y)+h\sigma_i^z\sigma_j^z$$

Assuming periodic boundary condition, and the number of site is large (say $N = 12$). Now I get some degenerate eigenstates. I know momentum operator $K$ satisfies $[K,H]=0. $I want to reduce the original H to the subspace with eigenvalue of $K$ equals 0 (which can reduce my calculation loads). But since some eigenstates are degenerate, they might not be the eigenstates of $K$. How can I solve this problem? I also want to find the subspace with Parity equals 1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just diagonalize $P^{\dagger} H P$, where $P$ is a $2^N \times d$ matrix whose columns are an orthonormal basis for the $d$-dimensional subspace of interest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know how to construct the momentum matrix for Ising model, especially I want to find the sector which momentum is 0?